# UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate delegate methods when app is in the background

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, swift4

Which of the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate method that is called whenever there is a push notification and the app is in the background? As one method is called is when the app is in the foreground and other is called when user taps on the notification. I intend to use the delegate method to update the application badge number when the app is in the background. The two methods called are shown below. Any suggestion or a better to achieve this will be appreciated.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
    print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
}

  print(userInfo)
}



func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
    print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
}

print(userInfo)

completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```

method reference: Firebase

Comment: It is possible to set the badge through the push message itself. Would that work for your case?

Comment: @marsbear it definitely works, but I was hoping that there was a away to update the badge number by using some specific UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate method call when the app is in the background.

Comment: why not just use `application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 3`?